# Merging kafka topics based on time and preference

Tags: apache-kafka, stream, iot, data-processing

I have  two kafka topics with GPS data ie one from IOT source and another from Mobile device. Both have the same data format. I want to merge them together based on time and also want to give preference to IOT source. A window of 5 second delay is permitted. What stack can I use to achieve this.

I have tried to do it with ksql but couldn't get it working as expected

Comment: Ksql should work fine for joins... Show what you tried, and why exactly it didn't work. Kafka has no way to determine "preference"